# How to call a Web API End Point which wont wait for response

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

We are calling a Web API End Point (EP) from a component and we don't want the component to wait until it gets response from End Point.
We are calling the End Point using the below code and the below code is waiting for the response from End Point.

Can somebody give some insight to achieve this. 
Thanks in advance.

```
var webAddr = "EndPointURL";

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);

httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = 0;
httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;
httpWebRequest.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", Token);
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("BatchId", 25);
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("UserName", "ABC");

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();   

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "EndPointURL");
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("???", "???");
    request.Headers.Add("BatchId", "25");
    request.Headers.Add("UserName", "ABC");
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.SendAsync(request);
});

// do stuff
```

Comment: Hi Peco, Thanks for your response.